# Sort list of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have this below list, getting data from api :

```
 const Studentdata = {
   "StudentName1": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "male" 
    },
    "StudentName2": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "male" 
    },
    "StudentName3": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
   "StudentName4": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
   "StudentName5": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
    "StudentName6": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    }
}
```

and I render this data like this:

```
Object.keys(Studentdata).map(item => {
    return (
         <>
             <span>{item}</span>
             // will use {Studentdata[item]} list to render ul,li
    )

 })
```

So, here I Want to filter student data based on is she/he is active, active true items should come first. Expected op is:

```
const Studentdata = {
   "StudentName1": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "male" 
    },
    "StudentName4": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "male" 
    },
    "StudentName5": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
   "StudentName2": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
   "StudentName3": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
    "StudentName6": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    }
}
```

I am using it in React js, So I need to exact format to render / re-render the DOM. Because, I need this "StudentName1" to displan student name under this I Will show his details. I'm able to get the below:

```
Object.values(Studentdata).sort((a, b) => b.active - a.active)
```

but this gives me:

```
[0: {active: true, gender: "male"},
1: {active: true, gender: "female"},
2: {active: true, gender: "female"},
3: {active: false, gender: "male"},
4: {active: false, gender: "female"}]
```

But if I render this I need to change the render method, So need the format I mentioned above.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sort the object's entries (not just the keys) when preparing to render, so that you have a sorted array containing the keys and the associated values at once:

```
Object.entries(Studentdata)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1].active - a[1].active)
  .map(([name, { active, gender }]) => (
    // render ul, li with variables name, active, and gender
  ))
```

Comment: May I know what is the term for the square bracket call in `[name, { active, gender }]`?

Comment: That's destructuring. Instead of `item`, you can use `[val0, val1]` to extract the 0th and 1st index of the array, if `item` is an array. Similarly, you can use `{ active, gender }` to extract the `active` and `gender` property of `val1`, if `val1` is an object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only using the `values()` to perform the sort, when you should be sorting the objects with the keys as well. The other problem you have, is that it is not generally good practice to desire your object keys to be in a particular order. It makes much more sense to change your render function to `results.map` instead of `Object.keys(results).map`. Here is your desired output though:

```js
const Studentdata = {
 "StudentName1": {
      "active": true,
      "gender": "male" 
  },
  "StudentName2": {
      "active": false,
      "gender": "male" 
  },
  "StudentName3": {
      "active": false,
      "gender": "female" 
  },
 "StudentName4": {
      "active": true,
      "gender": "female" 
  },
 "StudentName5": {
      "active": true,
      "gender": "female" 
  },
  "StudentName6": {
      "active": false,
      "gender": "female" 
  }
}

const sorted = Object.entries(Studentdata)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1].active - a[1].active)
  .reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
    r[key] = value
    return r
  }, {})
  
console.log(sorted)
```

If you remove the `reduce()`, you will get your desired results, but simply in an array. This is preferable, because the reduce is redundant, as you are turning it back to an array anyway with `Object.keys()`. Also while key order should be maintained these days, it still feels unintuitive to rely on it.

Comment: If I remove reduce() I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: I said, 'but simply in an array' if you remove reduce (the data is still the same). You need to improve your render function to work with arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Sort on `Object.entries`, then reconstruct the object in your map statement (using `eval` unfortunately to preserve the variable name):

```
const Studentdata = {
   "StudentName1": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "male" 
    },
    "StudentName2": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "male" 
    },
    "StudentName3": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
   "StudentName4": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
   "StudentName5": {
        "active": true,
        "gender": "female" 
    },
    "StudentName6": {
        "active": false,
        "gender": "female" 
    }
};

Object.entries(Studentdata).sort((a, b) => b[1].active - a[1].active).map(([ name: objName, { active, gender } ]) => (
    eval(`let ${objName} = { active: ${active}, gender: ${gender} }`);
    return (
        <>
            <span>{name}</span>
    )
));
```